# Winui3 Navigationview PanetoggleButton increase size

Tags: c#, winui-3

How to increase the button / Icon size for the PaneToggleButton and the AutoSuggestButton

I already looked at
[https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/NavigationView/NavigationView_rs1_themeresources.xaml](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[image]

```
<NavigationView
    x:Name="NavigationView"
    AlwaysShowHeader="false"
    CompactPaneLength="70"
    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
    IsBackEnabled="False"
    IsSettingsVisible="False"
    IsTabStop="False"
    PaneDisplayMode="Left"
    PaneTitle="Pane Title"
    SelectionFollowsFocus="Disabled">
    <NavigationView.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="NavigationViewItemOnLeftMinHeight">70</x:Double>
        <x:Double x:Key="NavigationViewItemOnLeftIconBoxHeight">40</x:Double>
        <x:Double x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorHeight">70</x:Double>
    </NavigationView.Resources>

    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem
            x:Name="GeneralSettingsItem"
            x:Uid="/Settings/GeneralSettingsItem"
            Tag="GeneralSettingsPage">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon VerticalAlignment="Stretch" UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Settings/General.png" />
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem
            x:Name="MonitorSettingsItem"
            Content="Menu Item3"
            Tag="SamplePage3">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Settings/Monitor.png" />
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>


    <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
        <AutoSuggestBox AutomationProperties.Name="Search" QueryIcon="Find" />
    </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>

    <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" />
</NavigationView>
```

With <x:Double x:Key="PaneToggleButtonHeight">70</x:Double> increase the size of the button, but not from the icon. In Addition the Button ist covert by the panel below.
[image]

Comment: I guess you'll need to bring the entire style from "generic.xaml" and playaround with it. It's not an easy one though.